# F ./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h:127] Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs. 0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

my computer get two gpus，it' s normal if I don't add this code in the context.

```
model = keras.utils.training_utils.multi_gpu_model(base_model, gpus=2)
```

but it will use only one to compute, i don't understand what's it means 'work_element_count > 0'. is it that i have not cleared the cuda before?

I have try some methods, reducing the batch_size, adding such code below:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
   model = keras.utils.training_utils.multi_gpu_model(base_model, gpus=2)
```

the error message 'work_element_count > 0' occur in the tensorflow basic source code file '*python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h*'

```
// Calculate the Cuda launch config we should use for a kernel launch.
// This is assuming the kernel is quite simple and will largely be
// memory-limited.
// REQUIRES: work_element_count > 0.
inline CudaLaunchConfig GetCudaLaunchConfig(int work_element_count,
                                            const Eigen::GpuDevice& d) {
  CHECK_GT(work_element_count, 0);
  CudaLaunchConfig config;
  const int virtual_thread_count = work_element_count;
  const int physical_thread_count = std::min(
      d.getNumCudaMultiProcessors() * d.maxCudaThreadsPerMultiProcessor(),
      virtual_thread_count);
  const int thread_per_block = std::min(1024, d.maxCudaThreadsPerBlock());
  const int block_count =
      std::min(DivUp(physical_thread_count, thread_per_block),
               d.getNumCudaMultiProcessors());

  config.virtual_thread_count = virtual_thread_count;
  config.thread_per_block = thread_per_block;
  config.block_count = block_count;
  return config;
}
```

but they seem to have no effect,any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Where does that line with `work_element_count > 0` occur?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't explain this problem clearly. 
'work_element_count > 0' occur in the tensorflow source code file 'python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h'